# The Trump Brotherhood

Tags: mathematics, probability

If you happen to meet two of the Trump brothers from the family that lives down the street from you (assume that the two are random selections all of the Trump brothers), it is an even-money bet that both brothers will be brown-eyed.

What is the least number of total brown-eyed Trump brothers?

Comment: I suggest you use the word least, or something like that, otherwise there is more than one solution.

Comment: Is politics *really* necessary here?

Comment: @Deusovi quite - also introduces the problem of alternative facts about the colour of their eyes or even if they're bothers at all!

Comment: Is the surname 'patented'?

Comment: @AmitabhGhosh Trademarked, and in many contexts, yes.  More importantly, invoking the sitting US President's surname without qualification is generally understood to refer to the sitting US President.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "politics" if it is completely neutral, right?

Comment: @Nat For your reference, http://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Trump

Comment: @Nat Dude, you are one uptight mushroom, aren't you? You might care about US President, rest of the world not. And 'Trump' might be the most known surname after Mr. Donald Trump was voted as the US President, but it still does not portray any factual connection between this puzzle and him. If you got anything constructive that points to solving this puzzle, please share. If not, please turn around and start walking.

Comment: Who asked about politics? AFAIK, it was Deusovi♦(2nd comment). To which, I asked was it patented? As the surname 'Trump' didnt stem in 1727 (tracing back to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Trump), for which I gave you the link, which sort of proclaims that Trump surname was there for a long time, to someone who wasnt linked to Mr.Donald's lineage. 
I could had stopped at my last comment, but then I think it is necessary to point out where the thoughts are coming from. All these mudslinging wouldnt had started if someone chose to solve the puzzle rather than asking gibberish questions.

Comment: See [Should we require that puzzles remain apolitical?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5799/25966) (cc @Deusovi)

Comment: Politics aside, I would argue that invoking the name of one of the most highly visible cultural references of today introduces an element of reality, and therefore confusion. Are we supposed to be pulling data from the real-life dynasty? Which generation? What even do they all actually look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There are 3 brown-eyed brothers and 1 non-brown eyed brother.

Math:

> The statement is equal to $\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+m)(n+m-1)} = \frac{1}{2}$, where n is the number of brown-eyed brothers and m is the number of other brothers. We notice that if you take $m = 1$, then a n cancels on the LHS, and then solving for n gives $n = 3$. These numbers fulfill the original condition.

Note that this is not an unique answer, as ffao pointed out. Another possible way for this to work is for there to be 21 brothers and 15 of them brown-eyed.

Answer (score 5):

thecoder16 has given one solution and remarked on another found by ffao. Here is the complete answer. (To the question "what numbers of brothers are possible"; the actual question here, after an edit by the OP, asks only for the *smallest* possible number; thecoder16's answer already resolves that, modulo a possibly cheaty improvement mentioned below.)

> First, take the equation in thecoder16's answer. Write $s=m+n$ to simplify the notation a bit. We have $\frac{n(n-1)}{s(s-1)}=\frac12$ or, equivalently, $2n(n-1)=s(s-1)$. Now let's turn everything into squares. Note that $t(t-1)=(t-\frac12)^2-\frac14$, so write $\nu=n-\frac12$ and $\sigma=s-\frac12$ and our equation becomes $2(\nu^2-\frac14)=\sigma^2-\frac14$ or $2\nu^2-\sigma^2=\frac14$. This is full of fractions, so let's lose those by writing $p=2\nu=2n-1$ and $q=2\sigma=2(m+n)-1$; our equation is now $2p^2-q^2=1$, with the extra condition (if we want integer numbers of brothers, which is probably advisable) that $p,q$ are both odd.

This

> is something called *Pell's equation* (which as usual means that Pell was neither the first to study it nor the one to discover most about it) and its solutions are well known. One way to characterize them is to say that $(p,q)=(1,1)$ is a solution, that $(5,7)$ is the next, and that if $(p,q)$ and $(p',q')$ are two successive solutions then the next one after those is $(6p'-p,6q'-q)$. You will notice that when we construct the solutions this way $p,q$ are automatically odd. In fact, if $2p^2-q^2=1$ then $q$ must be odd because $2p^2$ is even; then $2p^2=q^2+1$ is 2 mod 4, so $p^2$ is odd, so $p$ is odd; so any solution to our equation has $p,q$ odd.

Therefore

> the first few solutions have $p,q$ equal to $1,1$; $5,7$; $29,41$; $169,239$. Thus $n,m$ are $\frac{p+1}2,\frac{q-p}2$ which are $1,0$; $3,1$; $15,6$; $85,35$. The first solution -- which is the "cheaty improvement" I mentioned earlier -- is a silly one (you *can't* meet two Trump brothers because there's only one of them, so *vacuously* if you do meet two then the chance of both being brown-eyed is 50%; $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ have the same property although they happen not to satisfy the equation); the second is thecoder16's; the third is ffao's; the fourth is another; and there are infinitely many more, though even the third is getting biologically implausible.